# Which model to use

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, data-science

I am working on a dataset of an airline passengers for a month.

The inputs are like Date of booking, date of departure, time of departure, origin , destination  and the output is the fare class (Economy, Business, First)

I have been trying to predict the fare class for the other input data for the next week and the log loss

I tried with K-nearest neighbours classifier but my log loss is 0.9 which is quite high
Could you suggest any other model which I can use to minimize the log loss

Answer (score 0):

If the period is equally spaced, you can use time series modeling. You can look for trends in the dataset.